# Own AddRef and Release for Boost shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-ptr, intrusive-containers

I once heard that it is possible to map the `Boost` `shared_ptr` or `intrusive_ptr` reference add and release functions to my own implementations of add and release reference functions.

Is this really possible? If yes, can anyone point me to some resources regarding this feature?

Thanks!

Comment: I've never heard of that. Perhaps you're referring to [`boost::intrusive_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html)?

Comment: @Angew I think you're right. I remembered wrong. It's `intrusive_ptr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with `shared_ptr` itself; the only behaviour you can specify is the deleter. There's [`intrusive_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) if you want to manage your own reference counting.